# Solve an ODE---usual method no means

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve
$$(2xy-x^2y-y^3)dx-(x^2+y^2-x^3-xy^2)dy=0.$$

I find that all the elementary method do not solve it. So I turn help from you. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. How could you do such substitution, it is not easy to find such substitution...

Answer (score 0):

$y=x$ is an obvious particular solution. This draw us to change of function : $\frac{y}{x}=z$

[image]